# More than one facebook like on one Joomla article

Tags: facebook, joomla

How can I add more than one like in one joomla article? I wont to add like to every picture in the article. I know this is possible but I don't know how.

Comment: It is supposed to be one like button per article. You can have multiple like buttons on a page of article summaries if each one points to a specific full article page. You can set a url value in the like button properties that points to a specific page where it can get the opengraph tags it needs to post to facebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022747/facebook-like-button-to-like-individual-content-items-on-an-index-list-page